# Magento products not show up in backend

Tags: products, backend, magento-1.9.3.2

I have imported some products with Magmi. Until 1 hour ago all work well.

Now I can't see the products on the backend!...Frontend it's ok, only on backend.

This is a PhpMyAdmin screen , and you can see all my products.

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEgIK.png)

Comment: What status have your products ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have some issue with the **status** of products.

You should make all your products enabled and visible with this script.

Crete a file called `fix_status.php` in the **root** of the Magento instance with this code below:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::app();
$ids = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->getAllIds();
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
      $ids,
      array('status'=>1, 'visibility'=>4),
      0
);
```